# how to combine prefixes and suffixes in EXCEL?

Tags: excel

I have a list of prefixes, suffices and bases. I want to combine them to show PREFIX-BASE-SUFFIX, ie A1-B1-C1. How can I do that?

Comment: like: `=A1&B1&C1` or `=A1&"-"&B1&"-"&C1`???

Comment: This post shows that you clearly did not do any research on your own before posting.

Comment: I like Dirk's approach, I won't have to remember difficult formula names

Answer (score 0):

You can use Concatenate function in excel.
Select a empty cell and click on functions and type.

```
Concatenate(A1,B1,C1)
```

Where A1 is Prefix,
      B1 is Base,
      C1 is Suffix

You will get only for first column.
Double click on that cell and remaining will be convert to desired output.